# Use default generic type set on parent

Tags: typescript, generics

```
type TOptions<
  bodyT = {[key: string]: unknown},
  dataT = unknown,
  paramsT = Record<string, unknown>,
> = {
  body: bodyT,
  data: dataT,
  params: paramsT
};

type TAutoMock = TOptions<undefined, string>;
```

There's an existing generic type called `TOptions`, and I would like to use that and want to provide the type for `dataT` only, since I want the default set for `bodyT` & `paramsT` in `TOptions`. How to achieve that in TS, like in JS if we've a function with default argument values, we can provide `undefined` and the default will be used, what about in TS?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to *skip* a generic parameter (yet). There is at least one open issue [microsoft/TypeScript#10571](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) for that.